# How to use oneof as a type in proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, proto3

Given a message that looks like this,

```
message Event {
    required int32 event_id = 1;

    oneof EventType {
        FooEvent foo_event = 2;
        BarEvent bar_event = 3;
        BazEvent baz_event = 4;
    }
}
```

I want to define another map which uses the EventType oneof as a type. Precisely, I want to define something like this

```
message Sample {
    map<string, Event.EventTypeCase> someMap = 1;
}
```

But, this is not working. I get the error that

```
PROTOC FAILED: "Event.EventTypeCase" is not defined.
```

Comment: `oneof` is not supposed to be used as a "base class". Maybe [Any](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) fits your use case for the map.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to define another map which uses the EventType oneof as a type.

It isn't a type in the DSL, so: you can't. It is a conceptual grouping of fields in a specific message. The existence of `Event.EventTypeCase` is an implementation detail, not something that is not even mentioned in the DSL specification as far as I know (although `protoc` may or may not detect conflicts if you define your own `enum` or `message` with the same name)

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way of doing this, so I was wondering if I had missed something out. Thanks for clarifying :)